# How do I fix a NumPy ValueError for an inhomogeneous array shape?

Tags: python, numpy

For this section of code, I am trying to randomly choose either theta or mu to be zero. When one variable is zero, then I need the other one uniformly randomized (and vice versa).

```
N = 10000

random = np.arccos(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N))
zero = 0
choices = [random, zero]
theta = np.random.choice(choices)

if theta == random:
  mu = zero
else:
  mu = random
```

I know that `random` and `zero` do not have a homogenous shape.

This is why I got the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

However, I do not know how to fix this (I am still very new to programming). Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't really want to use `np.random.choice()` here, because it doesn't take an `axis` parameter, so it can't be vectorized. It would be better to create a boolean mask from a random variable, and use that to select whether the random value goes into the mu or theta variable. `np.where()` can do that.

Example:

```
random = np.arccos(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N))
mask = np.random.uniform(size=N) < 0.5
theta = np.where(mask, random, 0)
mu = np.where(mask, 0, random)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random index to an array instead of taking a random array element directly.

```
theta_chice = np.random.choice(2)
theta = choices[theta_chice]
mu = choices[1 - theta_chice]
```

Note: another answer provides a way to take independent random decisions for each of the N indices. This answer takes just one decision. Not sure what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code makes an array and an int variable:

```
In [277]: random = np.arccos(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1000))
     ...: zero = 0
     ...: choices = [random, zero]
In [278]: random.shape
Out[278]: (1000,)
```

Trying to do `choices` on the list raises the same error as trying to make an array from the list:

```
In [279]: np.array(choices)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[279], line 1
----> 1 np.array(choices)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.

In [280]: theta = np.random.choice(choices)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[280], line 1
----> 1 theta = np.random.choice(choices)

File mtrand.pyx:920, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

If I apply `choice` to the array, I get one value from the array:

```
In [281]: theta = np.random.choice(random)    
In [282]: theta
Out[282]: 1.3589184926442504
```

Similarly, a choice from a list:

```
In [284]: np.random.choice([1,2,3,4])
Out[284]: 2
In [285]: type(_)
Out[285]: numpy.int32
```

The type of this choice is further clue that it has first converted the list to an array.

Your `if` line will also have a problem.  `random` is an array, so the `==` will be a boolean array.  That can't be used in a `if` expression:

```
In [283]: if theta == random: pass
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[283], line 1
----> 1 if theta == random: pass

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Assuming you want the array for one variable, and zero for the other, it would be better to apply the `choice` to the `if` directly:

```
In [290]: x = np.random.choice(2, size=10);x
Out[290]: array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

For a single random True/False I'd prefer to use the `random` module, but you've already used that variable name, so I'll stick with `choice`.

```
In [291]: if np.random.choice(2):
     ...:     theta = random
     ...:     mu = zero
     ...: else:
     ...:     theta = zero
     ...:     mu = random
     ...:     

In [292]: theta, mu
Out[292]: 
(array([2.21440251, 0.70140386, 2.66193561, 1.52018933, 1.0636733 ,
        2.33811607, 0.98158435, 1.85139822, 0.27636737, 1.55758632,...
```

You could modify this `if/else` if instead you want a random float instead of the whole array (as in [281]).